# Static folder not reachable (Serving Angular apps on Flask)

Tags: python, angular, flask

I have an Angular app which I'm trying to serve from Flask server. The app runs on Flask but when I click a link on the app, the URL becomes **...../static/#** instead of **...../#** which results in **PageNotFound error**. 
Basically, /static is being added to path. Do the files have to be placed in a specific way to avoid this issue? I have tried changing templateURL but don't quite know how this works.

This is what I've done: created template, static inside application. Copy-Pasted my Angular UI inside app. Created .py file to run the app. Built the angular app using ***ng build --base-href /static/***. Then copied the .js files to static and index.html to templates folder.
The first page is alright but on clicking a link i go to ..../static/# which results in PageNotFound error.

**IN A NUTSHELL, STATIC FOLDER CONTENT IS UNREACHABLE!**

Also glyphicon isn't rendering properly when running on Flask but renders fine when running otherwise on localhost:4200. Instead it shows some other symbol on Flask. Some other styling also goes out of the window while using Flask but works otherwise.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work.

Just changed `<a href="#">` to `<a>` and it started working!

Answer (score 0):

Try building it using ng build --base-href or just ng build.
If this doesn't work then please show me your angular route and index.ts files.

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, i never server static files from Angula/React/Vue from flask using CORS, i normaly create a separete HTTP server for frontend, it is egual how the server will be with Docker and Kubbernets,but if you prefer in this way, you can do something like this

```
from flask import send_from_directory,

@app.route('/<path:path>')
def send_static(path):
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, path)
```